# Finding results dynamically in json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I'm retrieving data from an API that parses a currency in the URL (using this format: `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${crypto}&vs_currencies=${currency}`) and it returns data like this

```
{
  "bitcoin": {
    "aud": 44768
  }
}
```

The JSON format changes depending on the url.
How do I find the price when the currency is changed?
Thanks.

Comment: Will your crypto change or only currency? If only currency is dynamic one then you can use Object.keys(result.bitcoin) to see the key and get the value.

Comment: `Object.values(data.bitcoin)[0]`?

Comment: And I guess for completionist's sake, `Object.entries(data.bitcoin)` to get an array of the key-value pairs.

Comment: Yeah but I have to find the value of the currency (in this case AUD).

Comment: So `data.bitcoin.aud`? What part is dynamic? What have you tried on your own? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have `crypto` and `currency` already since you are computing a request URL.

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${crypto}&vs_currencies=${currency}
```

So when you are processing the response I suppose you can use these as keys to access into the response object.

```
const value = response[crypto][currency];
```